# Errors in Activity code in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I'm new in programming and I can't understand why there are errors on every `public void onClick(View v) { " and warning on "(new OnClickListener);`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //mana lapu parslegshnas
    Button matematikaslapa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.poga1);
    matematikaslapa.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener);

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), matematikaslapa.class);
        v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
    }

    Button fizikaslapa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.poga2);
    fizikaslapa.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener);

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), fizikaslapa.class);
        v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
    }

    Button kimijaslapa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.poga3);
    kimijaslapa.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener);

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), kimijaslapa.class);
        v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    //beigas

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace all the "new OnClickListener" by "this". However, I suggest you to read a bit before starting to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot declare methods inside methods.

Change structure like this

```
fizikaslapa.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener);

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), fizikaslapa.class);
    v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

to something like this

```
fizikaslapa.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), fizikaslapa.class);
        v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

Now you're creating an `OnClickListener` anonymous inner class instance and declaring the `onClick()` method in that class.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 matematikaslapa.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener);
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), matematikaslapa.class);
    v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
 }
```

to

```
matematikaslapa.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), matematikaslapa.class);
    v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
}
});
```

Similarly for other `OnClickListener's`. You are using a annonymous inner class and you are implementing the interface `OnClickListener`.

or

Make your Activity class implement `OnClickListener`

```
 matematikaslapa.setOnClickListener(this);
 fizikaslapa.setOnClickListener(this);
 ..// similarly for others
```

Then

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch(v.getId())
    {
      case R.id.poga1 :
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), matematikaslapa.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
      break; 

      case R.id.poga2 :
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), fizikaslapa.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
      break; 
    }
}
```